# Translate url regex pattern for django internationalization

Tags: django, django-i18n

I am trying to set up a multi-language django site, I have added the languages I need in my settings file and translated everything in my django.po file. I added the locale middleware and language blocks to my urls and they display correctly when I navigate through them:

/es-mx/help  --- displays in spanish

/en-us/help  --- displays in english

Now I want to translate the urls, this is my urls.py:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    url(_(r'^help/'), include('help.urls')),
)
```

I want to have the following:

/es-mx/ayuda  -- displays in spanish

/en-us/help  --- displays in english

But I only get 404s when going to the spanish url. I have tried adding the following in my django.po file with no results:

```
msgid "r^help/"
msgstr "r^ayuda/"

msgid "help"
msgstr "ayuda"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `msgid` and `msgstr` are wrong here:

```
msgid "r^help/"
msgstr "r^ayuda/"
```

you've mistakenly included the `r` in front, but this is not actually part of the string of the url pattern...

notice that in the url pattern it is `r"^help/"` ...the `r` prefix tells Python this is a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) and to ignore any escape chars, which is a useful thing when working with regular expressions

Everything else looks right to me, from my reading of the docs, so I think you just need to change them to:

```
msgid "^help/"
msgstr "^ayuda/"
```